# How to hide a notification

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that shows a notification (HTML5), but after some time I want this notification to hide.

Is this possible? How do I hide the notification?

My code to do a notification:

```
function notifyMe(data){
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        console.log("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted"){
                var notification = new Notification("FOTÓGENA", data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                   #hide the notification
                }, 3000)
            }
        });
    }else
        console.log('Por favor dale en permitir a las notificaciones')
}
```

Comment: You should learn do read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .close method of the notification api:

```
function notifyMe(data){
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        console.log("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted"){
                var notification = new Notification("FOTÓGENA", data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                   notification.close()
                }, 3000)
            }
        });
    }else
        console.log('Por favor dale en permitir a las notificaciones')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`notification.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close) should do the trick.